# Norm upper bound on difference of inverted matrices

Tags: matrices

I feel like I have seen this bound before but no longer can recall its source:

Suppose $A, B$ are square matrices with $||A^{-1} (A-B) || < 1$, i.e. their perturbation is relatively minimal. Then, what is an upper bound on $|| A^{-1} - B^{-1} ||$?

In my notes, I have:
$$
|| A^{-1} - B^{-1} || \leq \frac{||A^{-1}||^2 ||A - B||}{1 - ||A^{-1} (A - B)||}
$$

Is this true? And is there a source?

Comment: What norm are you considering ?

Comment: General matrix norms, ideally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $\|I-A^{-1}B\|<1$, so $$B^{-1}A=[A^{-1}B]^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(I-A^{-1}B)^n.$$ So $B^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (I-A^{-1}B)^nA^{-1}$.

We have \begin{align*} \|A^{-1}-B^{-1}\| & =\Bigl\|\Bigl[I-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (I-A^{-1}B)^n\Bigr]A^{-1}\Bigr\|=\Bigl\|\Bigl[\sum_{n=1}^\infty (I-A^{-1}B)^n\Bigr]A^{-1}\Bigr\| \\ &  \leqslant \|A^{-1}\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|I-A^{-1}B\|^n= \|A^{-1}\|\cdot \frac{\|I-A^{-1}B\|}{1-\|I-A^{-1}B\|} \\ & = \|A^{-1}\|\cdot \frac{\|A^{-1}(A-B)\|}{1-\|A^{-1}(A-B)\|}\leqslant \|A^{-1}\|\cdot \frac{\|A^{-1}\|\|A-B\|}{1-\|A^{-1}(A-B)\|}\\ & = \|A^{-1}\|^2\cdot \frac{\|A-B\|}{1-\|A^{-1}(A-B)\|}. \end{align*} This is valid for $A,B$ in any Banach algebra $\mathfrak{A}$, since we only used completeness, triangle inequality, and $\|UV\|\leqslant \|U\|\|V\|$ for any $U,V\in\mathfrak{A}$. In particular it holds for square matrices $M^{n\times n}$ with any matrix norm satisfying the inequality $\|UV\|\leqslant \|U\|\|V\|$.

Comment: Wonderful! This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

(and, as an aside, the underlying technique can be applied for the actual problem I wanted to solve. Again, we have A, B but instead want to study:

$$ || A B^{-1} - I|| $$
Via the series expansion of the inverse, the expression simplifies into a fraction with some ||A - B || ||A^{-1}|| terms, which is useful because B is a perturbation of A).

Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth noting that just because your first inequality holds, the norm $\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\|$ need not be bounded. As an example, choose $1\times 1$ matrices with $A=1, B=\varepsilon$ with $0<\varepsilon<1$. Then
$$
  \| A^{-1} [ A-B] \| = |1-\varepsilon| < 1
$$
but
$$
  \| A^{-1} - B^{-1} \| = \left|1-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right|,
$$
which is unbounded as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

This kind of argument is easily generalized to larger matrices.